# Mapping Census data on non-Census shapefile polygons using R

Tags: r, intersection, spatial-join, heat-map

Using R, I am trying to create a heat map of population in the five county commission districts in Alachua County, Florida, by merging total population data at the block level from the Census with the county commission districts shapefile, which can be found here[1]. Every time I try to visualize the total population heat map for the five districts, it returns a fill argument error.

How do I fix the code to visualize Census population block data on non-Census shapefile polygons?

```
#County Commission District Population Deviation by Intersection
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(spData)
library(tmap)
library(tidycensus)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

#Blocks from Census
download.file(url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020PL/STATE/12_FLORIDA/12001/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip",
              destfile = "/Users/*****/Downloads/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip", 
              mode = "wb")

#Unzip
unzip("/Users/*****/Downloads/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip", exdir = "/Users/*****/Downloads/", overwrite = T)

# Read into R
county_blocks <- read_sf("/Users/*****/Downloads/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.shp")

tm_shape(county_blocks) +
  tm_borders()

county_districts <- read_sf("/Users/*****/Downloads/County_Commissioner_Districts/Commissioner_Districts.shp")

tm_shape(county_districts) +
  tm_borders()

# Obtain Census Data
census_api_key("*****")
pl_vars <- load_variables(2020, "pl", cache = TRUE)
pop_total_2020 <- get_decennial(geography = "block",
                                state = "FL",
                                county = "Alachua",
                                variables = "P1_001N", 
                                year = 2020) %>%
  dplyr::select(GEOID, value) %>%
  rename(pop_total_2020 = value)

#GEOID Join
county_blocks <- county_blocks %>%
  mutate(GEOID = GEOID20)

county_blocks <- inner_join(county_blocks, pop_total_2020, by = "GEOID")

tm_shape(county_blocks) +
  tm_polygons(col = "pop_total_2020")

#Standardize CRS
county_districts_transform <- st_transform(county_districts, crs = crs(county_blocks))

county_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = county_blocks, y = county_districts_transform)
county_districts_blocks <- as.data.frame(county_districts_blocks)

district_pop <- county_districts_blocks %>%
  group_by(COMMDIST) %>%
  summarize(district_pop = sum(pop_total_2020))

tm_shape(county_districts) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")

#This gives total population per county commission district
view(district_pop)

#This should create a heat map of the county commission districts by population, but it isn't working. 
tm_shape(county_districts) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop") +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")
#The above three lines return this error:
Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)

  [1]: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/acgm::county-commissioner-districts/about
```

Comment: instead of writing those parts that need downloading and signing through an API key, you may just `dput(head(county_districts))` -which is where error pops out, to make this more easily reproducible. Apparently, from reading your code,  you don't have a column called `district_pob` in the `country_districts` object

Comment: @ElioDiaz Thank you so much for your comment, do you mean there is no column called district_pop in the county_districts object? When I look at the data frame district_pop, I see five population observations in the district_pop column each linked to one of the five districts titled 'Name'. The data is already linked so I am not sure why it will not display.

Comment: at the `tm_shape(county_districts) + tm_polygons(col = "district_pop")` the polygons function is expecting `county_districts` to have that column, you built `district_pop` object but you don't join them together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made two small errors. The **first** involves overwriting your `county_districts_blocks` sf object with a dataframe of the same name:

```
county_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = county_blocks, y = county_districts_transform)
county_districts_blocks <- as.data.frame(county_districts_blocks)
```

Correcting this by differentiating between the two objects:

```
county_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = county_blocks, y = county_districts_transform)
county_districts_blocks.df <- as.data.frame(county_districts_blocks)
```

or just commenting out the `as.data.frame()` command for now:

```
county_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = county_blocks, y = county_districts_transform)
#county_districts_blocks <- as.data.frame(county_districts_blocks)
```

should enable you to call the `class sf` version of your `county_districts_blocks` object in your next line (which has a similar error). This **second** error is similar:

```
 district_pop <- county_districts_blocks %>%
  group_by(COMMDIST) %>%
  summarize(district_pop = sum(pop_total_2020))
```

When left as above, I think you run the risk of overwriting your first `district_pop` object with your line `summarize(district_pop = sum(pop_total_2020))` so fix it thusly:

```
district_pop.sf <- county_districts_blocks %>%
  group_by(COMMDIST) %>%
  summarize(district_pop = sum(pop_total_2020))
```

When I call:

```
tm_shape(district_pop.sf) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop") +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")
```

I get something like the following. Is this similar to what you were looking to produce?

[image: example map of district populations]

Comment: That is perfect, that's exactly what I was trying to display! Thank you so much for your help. I am new to R and I thought I was reading data back into the shapefile but I guess I was just turning it into a dataframe. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help!